# Page Title gets Duplicated in MEAN.io

Tags: node.js, mean-stack

Any idea why my page title is displaying twice?  I am running a vanilla mean.io on openshift wih minor modifications other than basic modifications to a few values from default to custom (app name, meta tags such as keywords and description).  Thanks in advance.

/nodejs/packages/system/server/views/includes/head.html:
    6:   {{appName}} - {{title}}

Answer (score 2):

FYI - I simply deleted "{{appName}} -" from line 6 of

/nodejs/packages/system/server/views/includes/head.html

It appears that the  tag is populated with the value of line 40 from

/nodejs/config/env/production.js:

Comment: It comes from this btw `app.use(helpers(config.app.name))` `view-helpers` package sets some things up on `res.locals`